# Rails 4 filter has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given the following `DoctorProfile` model, how can I construct a query that filters `DoctorProfile`'s based on accepted insurances? I realize I can run the results through a block afterwards but I'd rather do this in a db query.

```
class DoctorProfile
  has_many :doctor_insurances
  has_many :accepted_insurances, -> { distinct }, through: :doctor_insurances, :source => :insurance_provider

class DoctorInsurance
  belongs_to :doctor_profile
  belongs_to :insurance_provider
```

Right now I have the following query and I'd like to be able to pass in either a single or multiple `InsuranceProvider` instances to filter out doctors whose accepted insurances are part of the array of insurance providers

```
DoctorProfile.where(:specialty_id => 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try this:

```
DoctorProfile.joins(:accepted_insurances).where(doctor_insurances: {id: [instance]})
```

Comment: close, this worked `DoctorProfile.joins(:accepted_insurances).where(doctor_insurances: {insurance_provider: [instance]})`. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
DoctorProfile.where(doctor_insurances: {accepted_insurances: [instance]}).references(doctor_insurances: [:accepted_insurances])
```

Should do the trick, pass in as many instances as you want and it will do a where in query.

Comment: I tried that earlier but received the following error `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column doctor_profiles.insurance_provider_id does not exist`

Comment: I updated my answer, I believe it is something like that. I forget the exact syntax

Comment: I think that's pretty close, I'll keep tweaking. getting `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "doctor_insurances"`